# Concatenate strings in COBOL without leading or trailing spaces

Tags: string, concatenation, trim, cobol

I'm having issues with this task; our task is to concatenate 2 strings without spaces in between those two, e.g.:

Input Alphanum. . 1: This string is
Input Alphanum. . 2: concatenated.
Input Alphanum. . 3:

Alphanum. output  1: This string isconcatenated.
Alphanum. output  2:

I can get these 2 strings together into the output, but they wont attach to each other without the spaces in between.

Comment: can you show us the code you have tried? I can write some code that will do that, but unless I can see the code you have written, I can't really explain why your code isn't working

Comment: You may want to have a look at `STRING stuff DELIMITED BY delimiter ...`, if you don't need the original strings to stay untouched you may use `INSPECT var REPLACING TRAILING SPACES BY LOW-VALUE` to create a delimiter.
Or, if you have a "recent" compiler produce some intermendiate "stuff" with `FUNCTION TRIM(var)`.
As SaggingRufus said: please always provide code you've already wrote which shows where the problem lies and what to explain.

Answer (score 2):

so assuming you don't know the length of the two strings, you would need to do something like this:

```
01 WS-INPUT-STRINGS.
   05 WS-STRING1 PIC X(100) VALUE "THIS STRING IS".
   05 WS-STRING2 PIC X(100) VALUE "CONCATENATED".
   05 WS-STRING3 PIC X(100) VALUE SPACES.
01 WS-OUTPUT-STRINGS.
   05 WS-CONCATENATED-OUTPUT PIC X(300) VALUE SPACES.
01 WS-COUNTERS.
   05 WS-LEN-IN PIC 9(4) COMP VALUE 1.
   05 WS-POS    PIC 9(4) COMP VALUE 1.

IF WS-STRING1 NOT EQUAL SPACES OR LOW-VALUES
   PERFORM VARYING WS-LEN-IN
              FROM 100 BY -1
             UNTIL WS-STRING1(WS-LEN-IN:1) 
                   NOT EQUAL (SPACES OR LOW-VALUES) OR
                   WS-LEN-IN = 1
    END-PERFORM
    MOVE WS-STRING1(1:WS-LEN-IN)
      TO WS-CONCATENATED-OUTPUT(WS-POS:WS-LEN-IN)
    ADD WS-LEN-IN TO WS-POS
END-IF
IF WS-STRING2 NOT EQUAL SPACES OR LOW-VALUES
   PERFORM VARYING WS-LEN-IN
              FROM 100 BY -1
             UNTIL WS-STRING2(WS-LEN-IN:1) 
                   NOT EQUAL (SPACES OR LOW-VALUES) OR
                   WS-LEN-IN = 1
    END-PERFORM
    MOVE WS-STRING2(1:WS-LEN-IN)
      TO WS-CONCATENATED-OUTPUT(WS-POS:WS-LEN-IN)
    ADD WS-LEN-IN TO WS-POS
END-IF
IF WS-STRING3 NOT EQUAL SPACES OR LOW-VALUES
   PERFORM VARYING WS-LEN-IN
              FROM 100 BY -1
             UNTIL WS-STRING3(WS-LEN-IN:1) 
                   NOT EQUAL (SPACES OR LOW-VALUES) OR
                   WS-LEN-IN = 1
    END-PERFORM
    MOVE WS-STRING3(1:WS-LEN-IN)
      TO WS-CONCATENATED-OUTPUT(WS-POS:WS-LEN-IN)
    ADD WS-LEN-IN TO WS-POS
END-IF
DISPLAY WS-CONCATENATED-OUTPUT(1:WS-POS)
```

You could put this into a paragraph and perform it over and over, but I did it this way to illustrate exactly what it going on. When you define a picture clause in COBOL, it will always to that length, so if I just tried to string the 3 variables together, there would be tons of extra space between them because each picture clause is 100 characters long regardless of what I put in them. I use these loops to calculate the length of each variable. First I check to make sure there is something in the variable, then loop backwards until I find a character.

You did not say if you needed to trim leading spaces as well, so I just assumed trailing spaces only. You could also you use `INSPECT TALLYING` to get the count rather than writing the loops

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UNSTRING` command with the `TALLYING IN` and `WITH POINTER` options to keep track of where you want to put the next string.